# Determine if SocketException from UdpClient.Receive was caused by a timeout

Tags: c#, socketexception, udpclient

I have a `UdpClient` receiving data with a timeout set, e.g.:

```
UdpClient client = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 12345));
client.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;     // 5 second timeout

while (!shutdown) {
    IPEndPoint source = null;
    byte[] data = client.Receive(ref source);  
}
```

`Receive` is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_UdpClient_Receive_System_Net_IPEndPoint__) as throwing a `SocketException` if "an error occurred when accessing the socket". The behavior of setting `ReceiveTimeout` is also [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout?view=netframework-4.8) as throwing a `SocketException` if the synchronous operation times out.

If I get a `SocketException` from `Receive` when a timeout is set, how can I determine if the exception was caused by a timeout rather than a more serious error?

I did confirm that the exception thrown on timeout is an actual `SocketException` and not some specific subclass of it. The only thing I can really think of is checking the exception message, which is a hack that I'm not really excited about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to examine `SocketException.ErrorCode` property for value `10060` (`WSATIMEDOUT`).

The complete list of `ErrorCode` values you can find here: https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2